# Why can't I find this agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)

Tags: user-agent

I was looking through my sites logs and by far the most popular useragent was:
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)
Being new at this I googled it but, other than other peoples stat pages, it's not explained anywhere in that particular combo Mozilla/5.0 and NT 5.0. Plenty of other combos but not this one. Why is this useragent so unique?

Comment: Could be a spam crawler. Anyone can makeup any user agent they want. If I wanted my user agent to be `Hello/Kitty 1.0 (compatible; Microsoft Bob)` I could do it.

Comment: So because I can't find it listed it's probably not a legitimate user? Meaning, if I work out how to block it I wouldn't be cutting someone off.

Comment: I wouldn't get too upset about user agents. I'd just leave it as an unknown. It might be a helpful robot that doesn't know any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string belongs to Thunder Downloader (aka [Xunlei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xunlei)), a Chinese download manager.

One of the numerous nasty things it does is that it provides direct download link to resources. 
For example, Anna visits your page and downloads `justin-bieber-baby.mp4` with Xunlei. Xunlei saves the file url and hash value on its server. 
Next day, Betty downloads `B~A~B~Y.mp4` from another site using Xunlei, Xunlei also saves the file url and hash value. Now Xunlei knows these two files are identical.
On the third day, when Cathy downloads `B~A~B~Y.mp4` from that site, Xunlei also downloads from your site as an accelerator. 
That means, Cathy doesn't visit your website, yet you'll have to provide bandwidth for her. 
Imagine a popular file (~100MB) which millions of people<sup>*1</sup> want to download. It could cost you ~100GB bandwidth but brought to you only one visitor.

So imho it's better to block this user agent.

<sub>*1: Xunlei has ~400 million users by 2012.</sub>